# create and populate combox with GXT (UiBinder)

Tags: combobox, uibinder, gxt

My question is just simple. I want to create and populate a combobox with GXT through UIBinder. I search anywhere but I haven't found. Please can one have an example for that ?

I'm using GXT3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't have the complete solution, but I think this code will bring you to the right way:

https://code.google.com/p/gxt-uibinder/source/browse/gxt-uibinder-test/src/com/jhickman/web/gwt/gxtuibindertest/client/view/combos/ComboBoxView.ui.xml?spec=svn147fc0190dcbfabc8b31366ae42c0b4484727de1&r=147fc0190dcbfabc8b31366ae42c0b4484727de1

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of data are you willing to populate. Say, for complex items (like, a full user defined /object) ComboBox component is useful. And for simpler items, like, Enums or Strings or Integers, you should rather use SimpleComboBox component. Either way, please visit the Sencha showcase. There are tons and tons of examples of combo boxes there.

Here is the link: http://www.sencha.com/examples/